# Weakref to an instance does not work after deletion, but works for the whole class when deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, weak-references, python-internals

Say we have a class `Test` which has a static method as so:

```py
import weakref
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        return 'Hello'
```

We create an instance of `Test` - call its method, we also create a weak reference to the instance as well. Then delete the variable and see if we can call the method again:

```
test_ins = Test()
test_ins_weakref = weakref.ref(test_ins)

print(test_ins.hello())
print("---deleting test_ins---")
del test_ins
print(test_ins_weakref().hello())
```

Before we delete the instance, it works (as it should) - but then it doesn't (Checking the type yields `NoneType` and it of course does not have a method called `hello`).
If we don't perform the `del` operation on the instance, we would get `<class '__main__.Test'>` and thus we can call the method.

Now lets try deleting the class itself:

```
test_ins = Test()
test_ins_weakref = weakref.ref(test_ins)

print(test_ins.hello())
print("---deleting test_ins---")
del Test
print(test_ins_weakref().hello())
```

It works.

---

My main question is if someone can explain what is happening here, because when I read the code I don't understand how and why it works that way.

Deleting a whole class doesn't mean that now all its instances point to nothing? Because, after deleting the class `Test` we cannot access the method nor create new instances..

```
new_ins = Test()
print(Test().hello())
```

Both yield

```
NameError: name 'Test' is not defined
```

However we can tweak things "around" and use the working instance type to create a new one:

```
new_ins = type(test_ins)()
print(new_ins.hello())
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html):

> when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its memory for something else.

That's why in this block:

```
test_ins = Test()
test_ins_weakref = weakref.ref(test_ins)

print(test_ins.hello())
print("---deleting test_ins---")
del test_ins
print(test_ins_weakref().hello())
```

the last line produces an error (the object to which `test_ins_weakref` references was destroyed by garbage collector).

In this block:

```
test_ins = Test()
test_ins_weakref = weakref.ref(test_ins)

print(test_ins.hello())
print("---deleting test_ins---")
del Test
print(test_ins_weakref().hello())
```

You delete `Test` but the class of the `test_ins` is still in the memory. It wasn't collected because it has a strong reference to it.

```
It can be seen here:
import weakref
class Test:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        return 'Hello'

test_ins = Test()
print(f"{id(Test)=}")
del Test
print(f"{id(test_ins.__class__)=}")
```

It will give the same `id` because the objects is still alive.
So when you do `del Test` you are not deleting the object from the memory, you are removing the variable `Test` that was referencing the object.
If there is at least one strong reference to that object, it won't be deleted from the memory.

That's why this block:

```
new_ins = type(test_ins)()
print(new_ins.hello())
```

works.